# How can I pass both Vertex & Face normals to a Three.js shader?

Tags: javascript, three.js, glsl, shader, normals

If I understand correctly, the ***THREE.Geometry*** methods, ***.computeFaceNormals()*** & ***.computeVertexNormals()***, each assign values to an 'innate' attribute array, "normal".

So, if I want to use *both* vertex- & face- normals in a single shader, I must:

1. calculate face-normals
2. clone the results (from 'normals') to a new attribute array, (i.e. 'fNormals')
3. calculate vertex-normals
4. render...

So far, using this approach, I'm trying this:

```
var shader = new THREE.ShaderMaterial(
    {
        attributes: {
            fNormal: { type: "v3", value: [] }
        },
        //uniforms, vertexShader, etc...
    } );

//load a mesh & assign the shader to it...

//setup both vertex & face normals for use in shader

mesh.geometry.computeFaceNormals();

//clone above face-normals to 'fNormal' array:

for (var i=0; i < mesh.geometry.attributes[ 'normal' ].length; i++){
  var cloned = mesh.geometry.attributes[ 'normal' ].value[i];
  shader.attributes[ 'fNormal' ].value[i] = cloned;
}

//now calculate vertex normals & place them in the 'normal' attribute:
mesh.geometry.computeVertexNormals();
```

EDIT: Ok, realizing some mistakes & editing this as I debug. Still unsure as to how to address the generated normals...

Thanks for any insights-

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access faces normals in `mesh.geometry.faces[].normal`.

```
for (var i=0; i < mesh.geometry.faces.length; i++){
    shader.attributes.fNormal.value[i] = mesh.geometry.faces[i].normal;
    //I don't think you need to clone the normal vertex here
}
```

This should work if your bind your attribute to the faces:

```
attributes: {
    fNormal: { type: "v3", value: [], boundTo: 'faces' }
},
```

You can find an example of how to use custom attributes in [webgl_materials_wireframe](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_materials_wireframe.html)

Comment: Yes, I was just getting onto the right track when your answer confirmed it. Thanks! I wasn't aware of "boundTo" until now. Still, I'm confused: Doesn't this set up an array of length equal to number of faces, when what I need is an array equal to the number of vertices?

Comment: @Jackalope You can see in [`WebGLRenderer.js#L2211`](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/renderers/WebGLRenderer.js#L2211) that, when `boundTo === 'faces'`, it actually uses the value from the normal for all three vertices of the face.